# Angular 2 - Is it possible to add absolute path to e.g. styles.78f022854070df211b2d.css?

Tags: css, angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

does anybody know if its possible to add the absolute path / domain name to the href for stylesxxxxxx.css in Angular Universal?

I have: link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.78f022854070df211b2d.css"

I want: link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.domainname.com/styles.78f022854070df211b2d.css"

thanks in advance

Comment: Angular Universal is server-side. You will see the page only on browser so why do you need that ?

Comment: If i view the page in google cache, the design is broken. Amongst other things, i want that look good.

Comment: Keep in mind that of you update your website (new hash in file name), the Google cache will be broken too.

Comment: thats another problem...it would be great if we could specify the style sheet file name too. Is it possibile to remove the style sheet file and put the styles inline?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--deploy-url` option when building but this will also affect the path for js files.

```
ng build --prod --deploy-url https://www.domainname.com
```